# update a column in dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: r

I have dataframe

```
df1 ->

ID Name
1  Test1
2  Test2
3  Test3
```

I have another dataframe df2

```
df2 ->

ID Name
1  Char
2  Float
3  Decimal
4  String
```

Now I want to update df1 name values based on names from df2 using ID

Now my df1 output should be

```
ID Name
1  Char
2  Float
3  Decimal
```

Please let me know how to acheive this.

Comment: I would try to be clearer about whether you want to do a lookup by ID, or just match identically numbered rows.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `match`

```
df1$Name <- df2$Name[match(df1$ID, df2$ID)]
```

---

Or as @thelatemail mentioned, this can be solved with `merge`

```
merge(df1["ID"], df2, all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: Also `merge` - `merge(df1["ID"], df2, all.x=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
library(qdapTools)
df1$Name <- df1$ID %l% df2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were looking for something besides simply this:

```
df1$Name <- df2$Name[1:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ID` to get the right names.

`df1$Name <- df2$Name[df1$ID]`

Note that this solution is applicable if the number of observations in `df1` is less than or equals to the number of observations in `df2`, otherwise, you will end up with `NA`. Also, the `ID` is the row number.